# Delete points on the map to remain only one for each plane in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, point, json

I'm trying to put on the map the route of an ads-b plane, I've managed this so far ...

Poblema is as follows puts all the points since I started to intercept him until the end what is not correct should remain only the last point that shows his exact real time location.

```
function addMarker(coordinates, data_no) {
            

            //console.log(coordinates);
            //var marker = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(coordinates).transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:31700'));
            var marker = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(coordinates).transform('EPSG:4326', map.getView().getProjection()));
            //console.log(marker);
            var zIndex = 1;
            
            
            var style_aircraft = new ol.style.Style({
                                      image: new ol.style.Icon(({
                                        anchor: [0.5, 36], 
                                        anchorXUnits: "fraction",
                                        anchorYUnits: "pixels",
                                        opacity: 1,
                                        src: "img/airport.png", 
                                        zIndex: zIndex
                                      })),
                                      zIndex: zIndex,
                                      text: new ol.style.Text({
                                        font: 'bold 16px "Open Sans", "Arial Unicode MS", "sans-serif"',
                                        placement: 'center',
                                        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                          color: 'black'
                                        })
                                      })
                                    })
            

            var data = data_no[0]+"/"+data_no[1]+"/"+data_no[2]+"/"+data_no[3];
            
            style_aircraft.getText().setText(data);
            marker.setStyle(style_aircraft);
            vectorSource.aircraft.addFeature(marker);
              
          }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `data_no[0]` is the id of the plane you could use

```
        marker.setId(data_no[0]);
        var old_marker = vectorSource.aircraft.getFeatureById(data_no[0]);
        if (old_marker) {
            vectorSource.aircraft.removeFeature(old_marker);
        }
        vectorSource.aircraft.addFeature(marker);
```